# STM32F1 - Using master SPI on bare metal

Tags: arm, stm32, spi

I've been trying to port some of my AVR code to drive a simple SPI LCD to ARM as a learning exercise (I'm very new to ARM in general). For this I just need to use SPI in master mode.

I looked in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf) for my device (STM32F103C8) and found that the SPI1 pins I need, SCK and MOSI are mapped as alternative functions of PA5 and PA7, respectively, along with other peripherals (pg.29). My understanding is that in order to use the SPI function on these pins, I need to make sure that anything else mapped to the same pin is disabled. When looking at the defaults for the peripheral clock control register, however, it looks like the other features are already disabled.

I looked at the SPI section in the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf), including section *25.3.3 - Configuring the SPI in master mode*. First I enabled the SPI1 master clock in APB2ENR and followed the steps in this section to configure SPI1 to my needs. I also changed the settings for PA5/7 to set their mode to "Alternate Function Output push-pull" (9.1.4). Finally, I enabled SPI1 by setting CR1_SPE.

From my reading, I had thought that by loading a value into the SPI1 data register after configuring SPI as above, the data would be shifted out. However, after writing the data, the TXE flag in the SPI status register never becomes set, indicating that the data I wrote into it is just sat there.

At this point, I'm assuming that there is something else I've failed to configure correctly. For example, I'm not 100% sure about what to do with the PA5/7 pins. I've tried to understand what I can from the datasheets, but I'm not getting anywhere. Is there anything else that needs to be done before it'll work?

Comment: I don't think having the pins configured incorrectly would stop the SPI attempting to transmit the data. It wouldn't go anywhere but the peripheral would still tx it. I would suggest the peripheral is configured incorrectly. Have you enabled the clock to the SPI? Have you enabled the SPI?

Comment: post your code, otherwise all we can do is guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you did not set `SSM` and `SSI` bits in `SPIx->CR1` register. SPI in these chips is pretty simple, for the polled transfers you need to set `SSM`, `SSI`, `SPE`, `MSTR`, correct format (`LSBFIRST`, `CPOL`, `CPHA`) and proper baudrate (`BR`) in `SPIx->CR1` and you're good to go.

Comment: You're right, I didn't touch the SSM/SSI settings, as I thought they wouldn't affect master mode. I'll update my post with code, thanks

Comment: @Triforcer - these bit affect master mode when you don't use hardware CS pin. STM32 are supposed to support multi-master mode, so they DON'T transfer anything when the CS is low in master mode. SSM and SSI serve as "software slave select" and the same rule applies - when they are "0", you won't see any transfer.

Comment: Setting the SSI/SSM bits solved my problem, thanks. The microcontrollers I've used in the past didn't have provisions for multi-master, so the concept was alien to me. I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted. It seems non-constructive for people to do so without giving a reason..

Comment: The downvote is most likely a revenge for my downvote given to the other (now deleted answer), because it contained a perfect example of "how _NOT_ to write code".